# Request Validation ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, request-validation

I've been searching all day and I'm pretty confused about preventing script from being submitted in my MVC application. Most of what I am finding is telling me how to disable request validation, which is not what I want.

In the web.config in the Views folder it states

> Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to
>   occur after the input has already been processed by the controller. By
>   default MVC performs request validation before a controller processes
>   the input. To change this behaviour apply the ValidateInputAttribute
>   to a controller or action.

That makes it sound like my MVC app should throw the 'potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected' error when I attempt to submit script tags, but I am still able to submit something like:

> `</input><script>alert("hello world");</script>`

And when I load the page the script has been added to I get a JS alert box.

Why am I able to submit potentially dangerous script? What am I missing?

Comment: In a default MVC4 application, request validation is enabled and you should not be able to submit a script tag as POST data, but you're saying you can? Have you modified the application in any way? Is it a fresh MVC4 application? Is the request definitely a POST (and is the action marked as such?)

Comment: It is not a fresh application. There are lots of changes/modifications and most submission are via jQuery 'POST' ajax methods. The last controller method I experimented with has the [HttpPost] attribute.